# Mobile Safari - AngularJS ng-if flip flops back on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, safari

I am writing an app with cordova, AngularJS 1.5.3, and Ionic 1.5.3.

I have a page that when the user clicks on a button, it toggles which component to render.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<div class="list">
    <weekly-roster ng-if="rvm.data.mode === 'week'"></weekly-roster>
    <monthly-roster ng-if="rvm.data.mode === 'month'"></monthly-roster>
</div>
<button ng-click="rvm.toggleView()">Toggle</button>
```

Here is my codepen link:https://codepen.io/aubz/pen/YazozL

It works fine on Android and Safari desktop. It also works on some iPhones but not on the iPhone 6. When the user pushed the toggle button the second component is rendered and then it flips back to the original one.

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-if` try using `ng-show`. Unlike `ng-if`, `ng-show` simply adds/removes CSS classes to hide or show the element. `ng-if` actually inserts or removes a DOM node, which could explain some of the funkiness:

```
<div class="list">
    <weekly-roster ng-show="rvm.data.mode === 'week'"></weekly-roster>
    <monthly-roster ng-show="rvm.data.mode === 'month'"></monthly-roster>
</div>
<button ng-click="rvm.toggleView()">Toggle</button>
```